# Is there a way to detach the update process for heroku

Tags: git, heroku

When I push my updated on heroku, I have the normal git's trace like this :

```
Counting objects: 48, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32/32), 3.06 KiB, done.
Total 32 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)
...
```

It's ok but my internet connection is very bad and I'm disconnected frequently. Many times, the update is not finished because "the pipe is broken". Furthermore, it's very long.

I'm looking for a way to "detach" the process from my machine. I did not found anything on the internet. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Thinking outside the box here: can't you just ship your application via some resilent way to a intermediate machine? Like a micro-instance (which is free) from amazon aws? And then ship it from there?

Comment: Must I be connected to the micro instance to do commands from there? With my internet connection, I'm not sur if I can.

Comment: No, you connect once and open a session with `screen` or `tmux` and deploy from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a host on a better network to "relay" the application to heroku.

One possible solution:

1. Create a micro instance (**it's free!**) on Amazon AWS. EBS storage if you intend to do that more than once, or Instance Store if you don't intend to reuse it. I suggest a Ubuntu EBS.
2. Copy your **.git** directory (or the whole application directory) using a resilient and break-continue capable network transference protocol/utility such as rsync. You can just copy the .git (headless style) and then check it out once it is transfered to this relay-host.
3. Once your git directory is on the relay host, ssh to it and open a screen session. Screen will not die if your network connection to the relay server breaks, you just need to "screen -R" and you will get back what you were doing after the reconnect.
4. Inside the screen run your `git push heroku master` and be happy.

You might have to configure heroku on the relay host, like you usually do to your development host.